# fedora "bash:  : command not found" for `ps aux |  grep dnf`

Tags: bash, fedora, command-not-found

I have installed fedora 23 and this error happened when i want to use grep in su mode user :

```
[root@alifed alireza]# ps aux |‌ grep dnf
 bash: ‌: command not found...
```

Answer (score 6):

You, weirdly, have a Unicode formatting character [200C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm), "zero width non-joiner", after the `|` in your command.

Where did you get this example from? I assume you are copying and pasting it directly from some documentation, and for some reason this odd formatting character got in there — I'm not sure exactly why, as I can't think of a good reason.

The error bash is giving you is literally correct. With the character replaced with a visible representation, the error becomes obvious:

```
[root@alifed alireza]# ps aux |200C grep dnf
bash: 200C: command not found...
```

The shell thinks that you're piping the output of `ps aux` to a command named that unprintable character with `grep dnf` as arguments. But, of course, there is no command by that name, so it tells you so.

Why did I suspect that this was the problem? Because bash's normal error syntax is

```
$ noncommand
bash: noncommand: command not found...
```

and in the error you reported, there's a blank where the missing command should be. If `ps` or `grep` were missing, it'd tell you `bash: ps: command not found` or `bash: grep: command not found`. And, since you pasted the exact command and error into your question instead of retyping it (awesome — always the best practice!) I was able to examine the results and replicate. (This happens as non-root, too, by the way — the `su` thing is a red herring.)

Comment: the funny thing about this problem is that i write both commands in root and non-root user with same keyboard !! and error happened with root user ! now, what is the solution ? thx

Comment: Now _that's_ interesting. You're actually typing this rather than cutting and pasting? Is this in a terminal in the GUI, or at the text console prompt. It may be that there's a language/locale bug.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2v96bg2/8  gnome-terminal interface in gnome3, interesting thing that now i tested command in non-root user randomly had error !! i do not know what is happen !!